# X connection to localhost:10.0 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown)

Tags: jboss

why is this error comes.  I started the jboss server and when i try to open the application in IE i am getting this error

Comment: What does your application do? Does it do any printing (on the server side) or image processing?

Answer (score 6):

I just had this exact problem because I was connected to my linux jboss server with putty and X forwarding activated.
In putty, I unchecked the option "Connection > SSH > X11 > Enable X11 forwarding" and now it works.
Hope this will help someone.

Comment: I had this happen because there was some java2d code (font metrics) executing on the server while I had a Putty connection to that server.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem as well. It seems to have been reported to jboss:
https://jira.jboss.org/jira/browse/EMBJOPR-65

I have this problem consistently when I connect with X11 forwarding and try and access the admin console with the X11 forwarding connection open. If I exit the user's shell session, then when I access the admin console it doesn't kill jboss.

Comment: This fixed the same issue in a WebLogic through a Putty session with X11 forwarding enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Another related report:
http://community.jboss.org/message/202074#202074

Answer (score 1):

I had to remove X11 Forwarding from the putty session (JDK 1.7, Tomcat 8)

Comment: This resolved the problem for me too, but I would like to know why having X11 forwarding enabled causes this to happen. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Seeme like your wine is not configured correctly, and can't connect to X server.

If you are not usind Linux or X server, disregard this answer.